# how to reverse engineer sqlplus login from jdbc connection parameters?

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm looking at a program that tells me how to connect to an Oracle database from Java that looks like this

```
 String url = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@a-b.c.d.e:50001:f";
 String user = "username";
 String password = "secret";
 String driverClassName = "oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver";
 ...
```

Is that enough information to figure out how to connect to the same database from the sqlplus command line tool?  If so what is the derived syntax for connecting?

Thanks in advance for entertaining what is most certainly a stupid question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Probably something like:

```
sqlplus username/secret@//a-b.c.d.e:5001/f
```

This assumes that the SID (the `f` used in the JDBC URL) is the same as the service name of the database.

If they are not, I don't know of any way to "reverse" engineer the service name from the SID.

Comment: +1 Though: In 2012, I still have to tell everyone my password when using sqlplus? :-(

Comment: @AaronDigulla: you can use an externally identified user account (which has been available for approx. 20 years now): http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/network.112/e16543/authentication.htm#CHDBIHHA